# I want to fill class members with default if they are missing, using generic in C#

Tags: c#, json, generics

I have multiple web requests that post JSON object and I have serializable classes with all the fields. For example:

```
[Serializable]
public class RequestOne()
 {
   public string date;
   public string information;
   public string subject;
 }

 [Serializable]
 public class RequestTwo()
 {
   public int ID;
   public string Data;
   public string message;
 }
```

And my method takes partially filled request class and I want to fill in any missing fields with default values declared in constant class.

And I want to **avoid** writing each method with for each request, like :

```
public static void FillWithDefault(this RequestOne request)
 { if (request.date.Equals(null)) request.date = DEFAULT_DATE;
   if (request.information.Equals(null)) request.information = DEFAULT_INFO;
   if (request.subject.Equals(null)) request.subject = DEFAULT_SUBJECT;
 }

public static void FillWithDefault(this RequestTwo request)
 {
   //do the same for the fields in RequestTwo
 }
```

I want to know if there is any way to achieve this using generic?

I want to do something similar to this:

```
 public static void FillWithDefault<T>(this T request)
  {
    if(typeof(T) == typeof(request))
     {
        //check each member in request and fill with default if it's null
     }
      .
      .
      .
  }
```

So that in my main method I can use like this :

```
RequestOne request = new RequestOne();
request.FillWithDefault();

RequestTwo request2 = new RequestTwo();
request2.FillWithDefault();
```

Can someone please help with idea on this? Am I overthinking on this? I'm new to generic so please feel free to advise on my code.

**Edit**

Sorry guys, I did not mention that I will be using this method for test automation. Those request contracts cannot be changed since it's by design. Sorry again for the confusion!

Comment: how do you determine what the default value should be? where does the value for `DEFAULT_INFO` come from?

Comment: @MongZhu I didn't include actual values of those constants but i declared those inside the class

Comment: oh ok, in this case, I would go for the answer by @CsabaToth. Use a constructor.

Comment: @MongZhu I edited my original post. I'm using it for testing, and the request class cannot be edited since it's developer's code. Thanks!

Comment: but in this case, every field of the classes gets its personal default_value doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generics are used when the types have common operations/properties defined so you can apply the same routine for each type in one place instead of declaring different methods for each type.

However in this case, you have two different types with different properties, so I would not use generics here. You can achieve it with manual type checking and using reflection to get properties and set them but it's not a good way and definitely wouldn't be a good usage of generics.

Overloading is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Use constructors. Also make use of properties. Don't gather the default filling code to one place, it's the responsibility of the classes so keep them there.

```
[Serializable]
public class RequestOne()
{
  public string date { get; set; };
  public string information { get; set; };
  public string subject { get; set; };

  public RequestOne()
  {
    Date = DEFAULT_DATE;
    Information = DEFAULT_DATE;
    Subject = DEFAULT_SUBJECT;
  }
}

[Serializable]
public class RequestTwo()
{
  public int ID { get; set; };
  public string Data { get; set; };
  public string Message { get; set; };

  public RequestTwo()
  {
    Data = DEFAULT_DATA;
    message = DEFAULT_MESSAGE;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry! I didn't mention that my code will be used for testing. Actual requests contracts cannot be changed. I edited my original post too. Thank you.

Comment: In case of testing you probably want to look at mocking frameworks: http://nugetmusthaves.com/Tag/mocking http://abundantcode.com/list-of-popular-mocking-frameworks-for-c-developers/

Answer (score 0):

you can use `property`

```
[Serializable]
public class RequestOne()
 {
   private string _date;
   public string date { get { return _date;} set { _date = value ?? DEFAULT_DATE; }};
   public string information; // same here
   public string subject; //same here
 }
```